# Flutter : Use generics for http response

Tags: http, generics, flutter

I am new in Flutter.
I migrate from android development by Kotlin to Flutter. 
I would like to get a response from Http Url. 
All of the server's responses are in one format and the type of 2 variables is generic.
I did it in Kotlin by this 2 class.

```
class BaseResponse<T> {

@SerializedName("IsSuccess")
var isSuccess: Boolean = false

@SerializedName("Item")
var item: T? = null

@SerializedName("ListItems")
var listItems: List<T>? = null

@SerializedName("ErrorCode")
var errorCode: Int? = null
```

And other classes and responses are like this:

```
data class TablesModel(var id: Long, var tableType: String, var tableCost: Int, var banner: String?, var onLineCount: Int)
```

And my responses are like this :

```
BaseResponse<TablesModel>
```

Now I would like to do it in Flutter.  Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For general json models in Dart is very common to use ValueObjects/Mojos.
You could use json_serializer and a builder to prepare the model classes yourself. Or a tool like 
https://app.quicktype.io/ that will generate the model from you from a json response.

Regarding generics, the proper way is to have an abstract model class and implement the different responses types in subclasses, or you can leverage the Type system passing a  argument so the compiler knows how to treat those properties.

The simplest approach would be to use the type dynamic or Object like jsonDecode doest, but you lose type checks for errors at compile time and autocomplete hints from the IDE.